# How to display if there is any data inside the {item}?

Tags: vue.js

```
 <template v-slot:default="{item}" v-if="category == 'details'">                  
                         <b-card  no-body class="overflow-hidden"                   
                         style="background:#EEF3F7; height:130px"> 
                         <b-row style="padding:20px" v-if="item >=1">
     
                            <b-col cols="6">
                                <b-card-text  class="text-left post-title" >{{item.bb_name}}</b-card-text>
                                <b-card-text class="card-text-info-time-slider text-capitalize">{{item.bb_age}} </b-card-text>
                                <b-card-text class="card-text-info-time-slider text-capitalize"> {{item.bb_dob}} </b-card-text>
                            </b-col>  
                         </b-row>                                                        
                         </b-card>         
                                          
                </template>
```

How to show display my template out if there is any data in {item}?

Comment: Do you mean that the `item` is an object? and you need to check if the object has `keys` and `values`, or do you want to check if the `item` is nullish?

Comment: @Mina it has keys and values, what i want to show is when the {item} is >=1 then i need to show the template , if is null then wouldn't show it

Comment: How it is an object, and you want to compare it with number `{item} is >=1` ?